# App crashes when running ios app in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I am developing an app with flutter.
If you run the emulator and USB debugging (xcode run) on a real device, the app runs and works normally.

However, if you run the app on a real device other than Xcode run, the app dies immediately upon launch.

Is the environment different between usb debugging (xcode run) on the actual device and the process of running the installed mouth on the device?

If it's different, is there a way to figure out what's causing the app to die?

If I need more information, I'll edit the question and add it. thank you

Comment: Open the project in Xcode and install a "profile" build via cmd-I

Comment: It runs fine and there are no issues. But still the app crashes when run on the device.

Comment: `profile` and `usb debugging` all work normally. However, the built app still crashes when I run it on the device.

Comment: Strange.  A build installed by the profile command should run without being connected

Answer (score 0):

change launch.json from debug to  "flutterMode": "release",

Comment: What is the path of `launch.json` file?

Comment: C:\Repos\project\.vscode